# Why would my CiviCRM CSS file not load correctly?

Tags: css, resource-urls

I'm having trouble with my CiviCRM CSS file not loading correctly -- the admin bar becomes a bulleted list of plain text.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm running civi 4.4.15 on D7.38
I'm actually having some issues site wide in terms of CSS.  I find myself frequently clearing all caches or running the update.php in order to get past a bug.

Comment: Could you clarify what not loading "correctly" means? Is the style tag in your page source at all? What resources are being loaded? Check your page source for Civi's header block with styles and scripts - is it there? Are the links correct? Also what happens when you disable Drupal aggregation?

Comment: the next time I have the issue I will refer to your questions to trouble shoot.  I cleared all caches again and that resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess it is likely an issue with domain name and/or HTTPS conflicts. In your `civicrm.settings.php` file you define a `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` which may or may not include the `www` or `https://` on the domain name. For example, it could be:

- http://yourdomain.org/
- https://yourdomain.org/
- http://www.yourdomain.org/
- https://www.yourdomain.org/

So my recommendation is to make sure that you forward the other 3 versions to the version you would like to use throughout the site. Then you may want to double check that the URLs set up in the CiviCRM Resource URLs page match (**Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs**).

[image: Resource URLs]

Comment: the field for extension resource url is blank on my installation.

Comment: @AsheHiggs That should be fine if you aren't using any additional extensions.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like my main problem was running the site in dev mode (no page cacheing).

I turned on page cache for anon users and also aggregate and compress .js and .css files (/admin/config/development/performance) and my overall site performance has increased dramatically and also seems to have resolved my .css errors.

One tool that helped me tremendously was using firebug to analyze page load times and errors.